# Get attachment from post

Tags: attachments

I would like to get the attachment from a post.

I want to display a button below each of my post with a link to download them. They will be PDF.

How can I do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ACF(Advance Custom Filed) for this please read document for this

> https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: Awesome plugin, I didn't know this one. Thank you !